# Options added to StringToNominal have no effect

Tags: java, weka

### Problem statement

I've been trying to change several Weka String attributes to Nominal attributes using [`StringToNominal`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToNominal.html).

Using the Filter without options produces the desired result for the class attribute. StringToNominal defaults to using the last attribute and the class is successfully converted to a Nominal

```
StringToNominal stringFilter = new StringToNominal();
stringFilter.setInputFormat(insts);
Instances filteredInsts = Filter.useFilter(insts, stringFilter);
```

However, if I try to do the same thing by passing an option, the class attribute remains a String

```
StringToNominal stringFilter = new StringToNominal();
String[] options = new String[2];
options[0] = "-R"; //Range option
options[1] = Integer.toString(insts.classIndex()); //The class attribute index
stringFilter.setOptions(options);
stringFilter.setInputFormat(insts);
Instances filteredInstsWOpts = Filter.useFilter(insts, stringFilter);
```

### MCVE

Here is a MCVE for the error. It produces the output "true, false". The correct output is "true, true"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.DenseInstance;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal;

public class TestStringToNominal {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Attribute> attInfo = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        attInfo.add(new Attribute("val"));
        attInfo.add(new Attribute("class", (ArrayList<String>) null));

        Instances insts = new Instances("test instances", attInfo, 1);
        insts.setClassIndex(1);

        Instance i1 = new DenseInstance(2);
        i1.setValue(attInfo.get(0), 0);
        i1.setValue(attInfo.get(1), "first");
        insts.add(i1);

        Instance i2 = new DenseInstance(2);
        i2.setValue(attInfo.get(0), 1);
        i2.setValue(attInfo.get(1), "second");
        insts.add(i2);

        StringToNominal stringFilter = new StringToNominal();
        stringFilter.setInputFormat(insts);
        Instances filteredInsts = Filter.useFilter(insts, stringFilter);
        System.out.println(filteredInsts.classAttribute().isNominal());

        StringToNominal stringFilterWOpts = new StringToNominal();
        String[] options = new String[2];
        options[0] = "-R";
        options[1] = Integer.toString(insts.classIndex());
        stringFilterWOpts.setOptions(options);
        stringFilterWOpts.setInputFormat(insts);
        Instances filteredInstsWOpts = Filter.useFilter(insts, stringFilterWOpts);
        System.out.println(filteredInstsWOpts.classAttribute().isNominal());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find this documented anywhere, but `Instances` seems to use zero-based indexing while `StringToNominal` seems to use one-based indexing.

Changing

```
options[1] = Integer.toString(insts.classIndex());
```

To

```
options[1] = Integer.toString(insts.classIndex() + 1);
```

Produces the desired output of "true, true"

The reason this is not immediately apparent, is that `StringToNominal` has no effect on non-String type attributes, so in the example, it acts on the zeroth attribute, a numeric type, without any apparent effects.